# Printing out a string array but replace a single element each time. Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

How would I go about printing out a string array multiple times and each time it replaces one of the words with a "-"?
If the array  had "Hello" "Hi" "Hey" then it should print

"- Hi Hey"

"Hello - Hey"

"Hello Hi -"

This is what I have so far

```
 public class SkipArgs
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
    int capacity = 1;
    capacity += args.length;
    String[] str = new String[capacity];

    for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<args.length; j++)
        {str[j] = args[j];
        printExceptOne(str[j], i);
        }   


}
}

public static void printExceptOne(String str, int j)
{

   System.out.print(str+" ");
}
}
```

I don't know how to go about replacing with the "-"

Comment: What's the rationale behind your current code?

Comment: You can use `String` class method `string.split("-");`

Comment: str[j] = str[j].replaceAll(".*" , "-"); to replace entire word with "-"

Comment: Umm, you guys should look at the actual code and read. Split won't do anything, it's already in an array, so why put it into a String to split by - which isn't in there. Also whats the point of that replace all? You'd be breaking the array for one and it wouldn't display properly because it would be `-HiHey` then `--Hey` and finally `---`. Also the replace all is pointless in this instance because it doesn't need to be replaced.  Cheers guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer loop should control which array element is not printed. So it might look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {
        // first print a separator if not the first element on the line
        if (j > 0) System.out.print(" ");

        // now print either the j-th arg or a "-"
        if (j == i) {
            System.out.print("-");
        } else {
            System.out.print(args[j]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's go over your code thought

```
int capacity = 1;
capacity += args.length;
String[] str = new String[capacity];
```

That means your `str` array has a length of 4, that's **NOT** what you want. it should just be:

```
String[] str = new String[args.length];
```

Now if you don't want to use `args`, you need to add elements to `str`:

```
for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++)
{
    str[i] = args[i];
}
```

Now that we made the array you can do the following:

```
String temp = "";
for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
{
    temp = "";
    for (int j=0; j<str.length; j++)
    {
        if (i == j) 
        {
            temp = temp + "-";
        }
        else
        {
            temp =  temp + str[j];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The - comes in in the below order

first line : first place
second line : second place
third line : third place

so based on the series this can done by equating the nested loop variables as suggested bu others.  Similar we can achieve any other logic